# What is the Japanese proverb for "even a thief is right three times out of ten"?

Tags: phrase-requests, english-to-japanese

> Even a thief is right three times out of ten.

I ran into this quote in a book about Taiichi Ohno, the creator of Toyota's philosophy. Does anyone know a phrase that corresponds with this translation?

Comment: This site could be helpful: http://jisho.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably 盗人【ぬすびと】にも三分【さんぶ】の理【り】, which is perhaps better translated as "even a thief has his reasons".